# How can I create a responsive layout containing a vertical scrolling element, wrapped within an element matching the viewport height?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, overflow

I'm struggling to create a responsive layout for the below plan, without relying heavily on referencing the height of other elements within the css.

[image: Layout plan]

Notice how the sidebar overflow does not stretch the page, and is contained within the parent element. The main `contentWrapper` element has a 20px margin around all sides. I don't want to stretch the main page and cause a scrollbar to appear on the body, I just want to contain everything within the `contentWrapper` element. The `contentTitle` element could be any height depending on length of its content. Realistically the `Header` element will always remain the same height.

The css I have included below does work, however it relies on referencing the rendered height of the `Header` and `contentTitle` elements within a couple of element height calculations to prevent the `contentWrapper` from stretching the page. However this is not ideal, as if, for example, the content title height changes when a longer line wraps, the `contentWrapper` will be pushed below the bottom of the viewport, and the body gets a scrollbar.

I don't want to have to rely on minussing rendered element heights, and would like to find a more flexible and responsive method of achieving this layout.

[Codepen of the below code](https://codepen.io/garywoo/pen/ZELWvez)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.contentWrapper {
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(100vh - 58px); /* Minus height of header and top margin */
}
.contentTitle {
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
}
.contentInnerWrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100% - 36px); /* Minus height of contentTitle */
}
.contentSidebar {
  background: lightblue;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.contentArea {
  background: pink;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<div class="contentWrapper">
  <div class="contentTitle">Content Title, this should be flexible in length <br> to support multiple lines</div>
  <div class="contentInnerWrapper">
    <div class="contentSidebar">
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
      <p>This sidebar should scroll</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contentArea">This is the main content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can definitely do this with javascript, but I will need to thing about it to do in CSS !

Comment: I would like to avoid using javascript, and find a pure CSS solution.